# Align conditions to right of equation in Word 2007/2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a multi-line equation in Word 2010 (Word 2007 should be the same) where each line has a condition, "if...." to the right of it. For an example of what I am talking about, see Equation 1 on page 2 of http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/390/Lecture1.pdf. My question is, how can I align the "if..." conditions as well as the main numerical part of the equation? I know how to align equations around the equal sign, but here I have to align items in two columns. Is there a way to do this without resorting to tables or manually putting in a lot of spaces?

Comment: As this seems like a "How do I use ProgramFoo?" question, I'm voting to migrate to Super User.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right place for this question, but since you have had no answers ...

In the Word document you can show the ruler and set [tab stops](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/set-tab-stops-HA010034129.aspx) where you want the equal sign to be displayed (highlight all rows that require this formatting first).  Then just tab and all will be aligned.  Do the same for the if clause.